# Database structure for food database

Tags: sql, database

I wrote a website for users to login and add foods to their own food database which could later be referenced as a list of "existing foods"

Each user has these options:

1. Add a new food to their database
2. Add a new food to their daily intake (from existing food database unique to each user)
3. Modify their settings page (set daily calories is the only option for now)

So far what I have (in theory) is:

```
users
=====
UID (primary key)
username
password

food
====
FID
name
description
calories
carbs
protein
fat

settings
========
SID
dailyCalories
```

How would I link these together so each user has a specific databank of food and settings page?

I'm also not sure how to handle daily intake. I'm thinking of manually adding buttons "start day" and "end day" to reset the daily tracking cycle which seems to be the best solution at the moment.

Comment: The business rules (i.e. what the data will be used for) should drive the schema. For example, the answer might be different if users are allowed to see/share definitions for food. I'm also skeptical about all the ID columns. Could you really have two distinct users with the same username? Could you really have two distinct foods with the same name? If not, why introduce the redundant column?

Comment: I trust that you're storing the hash of a salted password and not just the plain-text password.  You need to store the salt too, of course, either as part of the string from the hashed salted password or in a separate column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new table which will contain `UID` and `FID` and add a field in `settings` table `UID` which will contain the settings of each users.

Answer (score 0):

You add a Fourth Table That Links Each 3 together

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest

```
settings
=========
SID - PK - you dont really need it 
UID
setName
setValues
```

this way you wont have to change table schema every time new setting pop up

i would also add tables

```
group - so user can specify food for different days/meals etc
=========
GID - PK
UID 
name 
desc 

groupFood
=========
GID - PK
FID - PK
```

---- if all you want is simple join food and user use

```
userFood
========
UID - PK 
FID - PK
```

Answer (score 0):

Given only what you have described above, I'd probably use the following tables. But I reiterate my comment: the schema depends on the uses of the data.

```
Users
    UName (PKey)
    Password

Foods
    UName (FKey)
    FName 
    OtherColumsYouHave
    Primary Key: UName, FName

Settings
    UName
    FName
    DailyIntake
    Primary Key: UName, FName
    Foreign Key: Uname, FName => Foods(UName, FName)
```